# Insert files into database using Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, h2

I have written routes to move files from a source directory to a destination directory using Camel. I need some help in moving these files to a database. This is the route for moving files from one directory to another:

```
private static RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:data/outbox?idempotent=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}&noop=true&readLock=changed&delete=true")
                    .choice()
                    .when(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".log"))
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                            logger.log(Level.INFO, "File: " + exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName") + " has been updated");
                        }
                    })
                    .to("file:data/log");
        }
    };
}
```

How can I modify this route to insert the file into a database using components like SqlComponent? I'm trying to do this using an H2 database in a Spring Boot Application.

Comment: You can use the camel-jdbc component as your destination, as Gnanagurus showed in his answer. But, you'll need to build INSERT statements and put them into the BODY first. Also, you'll need to figure out what exactly you want to to in the database: do you need to split the file's records first? Does the whole file go into one record/. How?

Comment: I'm trying to insert the whole file as it is into the database as a BLOB type.

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
.to("file:data/log");
```

with

```
.setBody(constant("select * from your query"))
.to("jdbc:yourdatabase")
```

Also add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the same file from the route within an insert query? For example:
`.setBody(constant("insert into table values (1, <file>)"))`

Comment: Of course, once you poll the file store it in a header or property. Using simple expression pass it in your query. ${properties:cheese.quote} / ${headers.cheese.quote}

Comment: Eg: .setBody(simple("insert into processed_customer values(&#39;${header.file}&#39;)"))

Comment: The best idea would be (genereally followed in many org's) . Use base64 component and encode your file -> store the base64 to a header / property -> pass it to your query. I would even go one step further, use the GZip component, compress and encode it. So that it doesnt occupy DB memory so much

Comment: If any exceptions occur, the file is being removed from the original location. Is there an option to not delete the file if any exceptions occurred?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your message body is a FILE. You have to persist this. In theory, your could pass it to a processor that does whatever, including persisting it to wherever. Using more standard Camel components, you could go with camel-jdbc, or camel-sql, or camel-jpa.

Using camel-sql:

1. You can pass an insert statement as part of the URL.
2. Before that, you have to set up the parameters that will be used in the
   insert statement

The code would look like this:

```
from("file://c:/test/in1a?noop=true")
  .convertBodyTo(String.class)
  .setProperty("fileName", simple("${header.CamelFileAbsolutePath}"))
  .setProperty("fileContents", body())
  .to("sql:insert into TEST1.FILE_UPLOAD (FILE_NAME, FILE_CONTENTS) 
           VALUES(:#${property.fileName} 
              , :#${property.fileContents})?dataSource=dsTest1");
```

From bottom to top:

1. The insert statement is like the one you wanted (I've assumed a
   table with two columns). Also, I've assumed that you can use "named
   parameters" instead of "positional parameters". (If you have something earlier than Camel
   2.14 check the docs for other approaches)
2. Named parameters can simply be set up as properties before the insert statement. That's why we have two "setProperty()" calls before the INSERT.
3. Since the body starts out as a FILE, I start by converting it to a String. If your file has Binary data, you could convert it to something else. It needs to be something Serializable.

You might notice that the insert also has an option naming the datasource. This name (dsTest1) needs to be available. In my case, I have the following in my Spring configuration:

```
<bean name="dsTest1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1" />
    <property name="username" value="user01" />
    <property name="password" value="password01" />
</bean>

<bean name="route07Bean" class="com.mycompany.RouteBuilder07" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

</camelContext>
```

The dependency for your POM will be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
    <version>${camel-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

[Here's a link to the Documentation for the SQL component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to insert the file into the database. I catch exceptions, if any also. Is there an option I can use that will not delete the file from the original location if any exceptions occurred?

Comment: I'm using "delete=true" and the documentation says that the file will be deleted only if the processing is successful. I just need the file to be in the same directory if an exception occurs, for instance if there are any connectivity issues while running the application.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying issue is that you're catching/handling all exceptions. So, Camel doesn't really "know" that an exception occurs.

Comment: I'm using a doTry() doCatch() block.